# SQL - monthly count based on begin and end dates

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm new to using Teradata SQL and I need to do a monthly count of employees based on begin and end dates.  Let's say I have four employees' data, two of which are still employed on 4-30-2012, so it looks like this

```
Emp_ID        join_date          leave_date
1             1-1-2012           2-02-2012
2             1-17-2012          3-4-2012
3             2-1-2012           1-1-9999
4             3-20-2012          1-1-9999
```

Desired output:

```
MonthEnd         Emp_Count
1-31-2012           2
2-29-2012           2
3-31-2012           1
4-30-2012           2
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, than to just UNION ALL a bunch of Selects?

```
select
'1-31-2012' as MonthEnd
Count(Emp_ID) as Emp_Count
where join_date <= MonthEnd and leave_date > MonthEnd
UNION ALL 
select
'2-29-2012' as MonthEnd
Count(Emp_ID) as Emp_Count
where join_date <= MonthEnd and leave_date > MonthEnd
UNION ALL 
select
'3-31-2012' as MonthEnd
Count(Emp_ID) as Emp_Count
where join_date <= MonthEnd and leave_date > MonthEnd
UNION ALL 
select
'4-30-2012' as MonthEnd
Count(Emp_ID) as Emp_Count
where join_date <= MonthEnd and leave_date > MonthEnd
```

Also ignore data formatting issues, as these are taken care of already.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? It is exactly what I am trying to do and struggling with it

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL way to do this is to put the dates into a table or subquery and then use `left outer join` and `group by` to get the counts.  Here is an example:

```
select dates.MonthEnd, COUNT(*)
from (select cast('2012-01-31' as date) as MonthEnd union all
      select '2012-02-29' union all
      . . .
     ) dates left outer join
     employees e
     on e.join_date <= dates.MonthEnd and (e.leave_Date > MonthEnd or e.leave_Date is null)
group by dates.MonthEnd
order by dates.MonthEnd;
```

Answer (score 1):

In TD13.10 you might use EXPAND ON to create one row for each month within the employement period

```
SELECT MonthEnd, COUNT(*)
FROM
 (
   SELECT 
      BEGIN(pd) AS MonthEnd
   FROM tab 
   EXPAND ON PERIOD(join_date, leave_date) AS pd
   BY ANCHOR MONTH_END -- one row for each month end 
   FOR PERIOD (DATE '2012-01-01', DATE '2012-05-30') -- the range of dates required for output 
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Dieter

Answer (score 0):

>

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Emp_ID] int, [join_date] datetime, [leave_date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
([Emp_ID], [join_date], [leave_date])
VALUES
(1, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-02-02 00:00:00'),
(2, '2012-01-17 00:00:00', '2012-03-04 00:00:00'),
(3, '2012-02-01 00:00:00', '9999-01-01 00:00:00'),
(4, '2012-03-20 00:00:00', '9999-01-01 00:00:00')
;





declare @output table 
(monthyear nvarchar(10),ENDING_MONTH nvarchar(10))


insert into @output
select convert(nvarchar(5),month(join_date)) + convert(nvarchar(10),year(join_date)) 
as 'monthyear', 
convert(date,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,join_date)+1,0))) as ENDING_MONTH
from Table1


select ENDING_MONTH, count(ENDING_MONTH) from @output group by ENDING_MONTH
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f00fc/40)